# How to get bootstrap modal multiple checkbox value in react?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

How can I get the multiple checked checkbox value in react? The checked checkboxes are in the *bootstrap* modal.

I have tried to get the checkbox value using state but it is not working.

To open the *bootstrap* modal:

```
<a
  variant="primary"
  onClick={this.handleShow}
  style={{ cursor: 'pointer', fontWeight: '700', fontSize: '16px' }}
>
  <b>Choose Employee Under Him/Her</b>
</a>
```

The Body of the *bootstrap* modal with the checkbox:

```
<Modal.Body>
  <div class="form-group" id="sampleTableForEmployee">
    <table className="table table-hover table-bordered" id="sampleTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Employee ID</th>
          <th>Select</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {(() => {
          if (this.state.allemployees && this.state.allemployees.length > 0) {
            return this.state.allemployees.map(employee => (
              <tr key={employee.empmainid}>
                <td>{employee.empname}</td>
                <td>{employee.empid}</td>
                <td>
                  <input
                    onChange={this.handleCheckbox}
                    className=""
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="allemployyes1[]"
                    value={employee.empmainid}
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
            ));
          } else {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td colSpan="3" className="text-center" style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '20px' }}>
                  Sorry, There are no employees under the selected department
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          }
        })()}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div className="form-group">
    <button
      type="submit"
      className="btn btn-primary pull-right"
      id="btnContactUs"
      onClick={this.handleHide}
    >
      DONE
    </button>
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
</Modal.Body>
```

I have defined `this.state = {allemployees1: []}`

The method that handles the checkbox:

```
handleCheckbox(event, isChecked, value) {
  var newArray = this.state.allemployyes1.slice();
  newArray.push(event.target.value);
  this.setState({ allemployyes1: newArray });
  console.log(this.state.allemployyes1);
}
```

Comment: Try this and check what happens after setState `this.setState({ allemployyes1: newArray },()=>console.log(this.state));`

Comment: Also in your code you have used `value` attribute for `checkbox` which is wrong. You won't get value like this, you need `refs` to get `checkbox` status i.e. checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your click event function, and your render method.

```
// The event handle function takes only one argument
handleCheckbox(event) {
    const {value, checked} = event.target; // get id and checked status
    var allemployyes1 = this.state.allemployyes1.slice();

    // Add to an array if checked and remove - if uncheck
    if (checked) {
        allemployyes1.push(value);
    } else {
        allemployyes1 = allemployyes1.filter(id => id !== value);
    }

    this.setState({ allemployyes1: allemployyes1 });
}


// You should set the checked status to the checkbox via checked attr
<tbody>
    {(() => {
        if (this.state.allemployees && this.state.allemployees.length > 0) {
            return (this.state.allemployees.map((employee) => (
                <tr key={employee.empmainid}>
                    <td>{employee.empname}</td>
                    <td>{employee.empid}</td>
                    <td><input onChange={this.handleCheckbox} className="" type="checkbox" name={employee.empmainid} value={employee.empmainid} checked={this.state.allemployyes1.includes(employee.empmainid)} /></td>
                </tr>))
        } else {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan="3" className="text-center" style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '20px' }}>Sorry, There are no employees under the selected department</td>
                </tr>
            )
        }
    })()}
</tbody>
```

This code should wrok.